# return of wrong output list permutation

Tags: python

I Have Written a program for permutation of [1,2,3], but i get some wrong output.
the output is like is this

```
[[1, 2, 3]] 
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
[[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
-----
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
-----
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

and return value is just same as initial list can anyone look at this ?

```
from typing import List
def permute(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    
    def fact(n):
        pr = 1
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            pr = pr*i
        return pr
    
    def get_per(arr):
        rindex = -1
        n = len(arr)
        for i in range(1,n):
            if arr[i] > arr[i-1]:
                rindex = i
        if rindex == -1:
            return arr.sort()
        pindex = rindex
        for i in range(rindex,n):
            if arr[i] > arr[rindex-1] and arr[i] < arr[pindex]:
                pindex = i
        arr[rindex-1],arr[pindex] = arr[pindex],arr[rindex-1]
        arr[rindex:] = sorted(arr[rindex:])
        return arr
    
    ans = []
    k = fact(len(nums))
    
    while k != 0:
        ans.append(nums)
        print(ans)
        nums = get_per(nums)
        k -= 1
    print('-----')
    print(ans)
    print('-----')
    return ans

print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

[Output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYX0U.png)

Comment: `ans.append(nums)` Looks like you are appending the same list over and over.

Comment: nums = get_per(nums)
is updateing the nums, and in print the the update nums are showing as appended.

Comment: Yes but `def get_per(arr): .... return arr`.

Comment: Just to test I added `arr = arr.copy()` as the first line of `get_per` and I got `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]` as output.

Comment: thanks @JohnnyMopp it was helpful, can you explain the reason behind it ?

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the in-build permutations in python

```
In [1]: from itertools import permutations

In [2]: list(permutations([1,2,3]))
Out[2]: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this way, but it was a question in a company interview. So how they will think over it  :).
Can you please look bug in my process.

Comment: Plus using the in-build function gives wrong result for [1,1,2]
Output -> [[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,1]]
Expected -> [[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1]]